How to find the keys of the values in a json using forEach and change the values of the relevant keys using typescript vue js?
checkedData has value
{ 0: 'infoclient', 1: 'warnmanager', 2: 'errorserver', 3: 'warnpublic', 4: 'errornetwork'}

masks has value
['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc']

tracelogMaskData has values
{ client: 8, manager: 15, server: 7, public: 18,network: 6 }

In the below code, after I find the index within for loop, I want to do some manipulations using the index value. I want to change the values inside tracelogMaskData with the manipulated index value. Before that I want to do some mapping between checkedData and tracelogData.
For eg: checkedData has 'infoclient' which contains one of the mask values. So the index is 0. Lets say the manipulated value is "2 to the power 0".
Now I want tracelogMaskData to be
{ client: 1, manager: 2, server: 4, public: 2,network: 4 }

Here's the code.
const indexes = Object.values(checkedData).forEach((c) => {
  const index = masks.value.findIndex((m) => c.startsWith(m));
  console.log(index); // do something with the index here...
  Object.values(tracelogMaskData).forEach((t) => {
    console.log('c & t values outside if>>>>>>>>>>>>>', c, t);
  });
});

I'm able to fetch c and t values here. I'm trying to fetch the keys to the relevant t values. Also, How to change the values inside t. Also, I want to know if this code can be simplified further.

Why is only the client value changed? Wouldn't the others also change?

Can you explain more on this trying to fetch the keys to the relevant t values. Also, How to change the values inside t? What is the logic that you need to use to change the t value.

@Phil Others would change too. Missed updating. Edited the question now

Your checkedData object doesn't seem very useful. It appears to be attempting to create a relationship between the keys of tracelogMaskData and the values in masks but in a way that makes it very difficult. Where do these data structures come from and can they be changed?

@YashMaheshwari Here t values would be  8.15,7.18.6. I want to find the keys of these values which would be client,manager,server, public and network. These values of the relevant keys would be changed to "2 to the power of index" like I have pointed out in the example

Without a delimiter between the field names and mask values in checkedData, you're limited to a pretty nasty O(n^2) search algorithm.
Iterate the values in checkedData, find the corresponding masks index (and value) then extract the field name by removing the mask value suffix.


const checkedData = {0: 'infoclient', 1: 'warnmanager', 2: 'errorserver', 3: 'warnpublic', 4: 'errornetwork'};
const masks = {value: ['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc']};
const tracelogMaskData = { client: 8, manager: 15, server: 7, public: 18, network: 6 };

// this has terrible time complexity but without a delimiter in the keys,
// it's the best you can do
Object.values(checkedData).forEach((key) => {
  // find the mask index
  const exp = masks.value.findIndex((mask) => key.startsWith(mask));
  
  if (exp !== -1) {
    const field = key.slice(masks.value[exp].length);
    if (Object.hasOwn(tracelogMaskData, field)) {
      tracelogMaskData[field] = 2 ** exp;
    }
  }
});

console.log('tracelogMaskData:', tracelogMaskData);




Instead of using Object.values, you can use Object.entries to get the keys and values. Also to change the value of t directly update the object key.
Object.entries(tracelogMaskData).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
  tracelogMaskData[key] = 2 ** index
});

Also, if you do not want to use value of the object for adding a check, then you can simply use Object.keys and update the value.
Object.keys(tracelogMaskData).forEach(key, index) => {
  tracelogMaskData[key] = 2 ** index
});

